# jUnit and Guava, comparing list equality after transform()

Tags: java, junit, guava

In a jUnit test, I want to get some rows from the database based on the `name` column.  I then want to test that the rows I got have the names I expected.  I have the following:

```
Set<MyClass> typesToGet = MyClassFactory.createInstances("furniture",
    "audio equipment");
Collection<String> namesToGet = Collections2.transform(typesToGet,
    new NameFunction<MyClass, String>());
List<MyClass> typesGotten = _svc.getAllByName(typesToGet);
assertThat(typesGotten.size(), is(typesToGet.size()));
Collection<String> namesGotten = Collections2.transform(typesGotten,
    new NameFunction<ItemType, String>());
assertEquals(namesToGet, namesGotten); // fails here
```

I currently get this failure:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected: com.google.common.collect.Collections2$TransformedCollection<[audio equipment, furniture]> but was: com.google.common.collect.Collections2$TransformedCollection<[audio equipment, furniture]>

So what's the cleanest, most concise way to test that I got rows back from the database whose `name` column matches the names I said I wanted?  I could have a `for` loop iterating through and checking that each name in one list exists in the other, but I was hoping to be more concise.  Something like the following pseudocode would be nice:

```
List<MyClass> typesGotten = ...;
["furniture", "audio equipment"].equals(typesGotten.map(type => type.getName()))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `containsAll()` two times to check that you don't have any missing value or any unexpected value.

```
assertTrue(namesToGet.containsAll(namesGotten));
assertTrue(namesGotten.containsAll(namesToGet));
```

---

But if you decide to use `List` or `Set` instead of `Collection`, the interface contract specify that a `List` is equal to another `List` ([same for `Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)) [iff both contains the same values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.) **In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.** This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.

---

**Resources:**

- [Javadoc: `Collection.containsAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29)
- [Javadoc: `List.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [Javadoc: `Set.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: @ColinHerbert What could be the actual reason for the assertion failure? In my case, the list entries are Apache Avro Records. All contents are the same, but still the equality assertion is failing.

Answer (score 6):

If you expect them to contain the same elements, but not necessarily in the same order, then just do an `ImmutableSet` copy of them both and check that those sets are equal.  If you expect them to have the same order, then do `ImmutableList` copies and check that those are equal.

`Collection` doesn't really have any notion of equality at all.

Answer (score 6):

The neatest and most expressive way of writing such an assertion is with a Hamcrest matcher:

```
assertThat(namesGotten, containsInAnyOrder(namesToGet))
```

Comment: I think I found `containsInAnyOrder` described on http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.2.1/hamcrest-library-1.2.1-javadoc.jar!/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html but I don't see documentation about it.  Do you know if it confirms the two collections have the same size, that collection 1 has nothing but items found in collection 2, and that collection 2 has nothing but items found in collection 1?

Comment: The Hamcrest documentation is a bit lacking in this area, so it is worth trying a few matchers out to convince yourself that they are doing the right thing. Alternatively, the source code is at http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.java?r=480. Yes, it checks that collection 1 has all elements of collection 2, and vice versa, and hence that they are the same size.

Answer (score 3):

Guava has a method that I find communicates well the concept you are trying to get: [symmetricDifference](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29). If the symmetricDifference is empty, the sets are equal.

```
assetTrue(Sets.symmetricDifference(namesToGet, namesGotten).isEmpty());
```

It may not be, however, the "cheapest", as it performs a union, intersection, and a difference operation. You could also check if the sets are the same size—if they are not, they do not contain the same elements, while if they are, you can verify that the (asymmetric) [difference](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) is empty.

```
assertEquals(namesToGet.size(), namesGotten.size());
assertTrue(Sets.difference(namesToGet, namesGotten));
```